# ASP.NET core - Configuration file not being mapped to POCO

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have read plenty of similar-ish questions, yet nothing worked for me. I am most likely doing something wrong but I don't see what.

Below is the config file I created, called `ErrorCodes.json` at the root of the project (same level as `appsettings.json`):

```
{
  "ErrorMap": {
    "Type": {
      "Input": {
        "Null": {
          "Code": "ABC-1000",
          "Message": "The request body is null or empty"
        },
        "Name": {
          "Code": "ABC-1001",
          "Message": "The 'name' property was not set"
        },
        "Age": {
          "Code": "ABC-1002",
          "Message": "The 'age' property was not set"
        },
        "Email": {
          "Code": "ABC-1003",
          "Message": "The 'email' property was not set"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In `startup.cs` I have the following constructor:

```
public Startup()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("ErrorCodes.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);

    this.configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

And my `ConfigureServices` method is here:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ErrorMap>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(ErrorMap)));
    services.AddSingleton(
        context => context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ErrorMap>>().Value);
    )
    services.AddSingleton<ErrorCodeConfig>();
    // some other stuff
}
```

ErrorCodeConfig is a "bean" (not sure about the name for that in the C# world) that depends on `ErrorMap`, it's defined as such:

```
public class ErrorCodeConfig
{
    private readonly ErrorMap _errors;

    public ErrorCodeConfig(ErrorMap errors)
    {
        _errors = errors;
    }

    public Error Get(string typeKey, string errorKey)
    {
        return _errors.Get(typeKey, errorKey);
    }
}
```

The class `ErrorMap` and `Error` are defined as such:

```
public class ErrorMap
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Error>> Type;

    public Error Get(string key, string key2)
    {
        return Type.GetValueOrDefault(key).GetValueOrDefault(key2);
    }
}

public class Error
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I can run the application, everything gets injected properly except the `Dictionary` in the `ErrorMap` class. It remains `null` and I am not sure why.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- I used a wrong name in the `ConfigurationBuilder` to see if it was a read problem, so I temporarily renamed my file, and as it could not find it it threw an exception. So I'm assuming that at the very least it can find the file.
- I appended appsettings.json with my `ErrorMap` block to see if I could have it injected with the default config file, but I got no luck. It didn't crash but the config class was still not populated.

Would you have any ideas of what I did wrong in my project?
Thanks for reading

Comment: Have you try to add getter/setter to `Type` like `public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Error>> Type { get; set; }`?

Comment: Oh yes, I tried that too. I even tried having a `readonly` property and a full-parameter constructor to see if it was working, it was complaining because there was no parameterless constructors, so I knew I was close but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on my computer with

```
var errorMap = new ErrorMap();
Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ErrorMap)).Bind(errorMap);
```

with this version of ErrorMap

```
public class ErrorMap
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Error>> Type { get; set; }

    public Error Get(string key, string key2)
    {
        return Type.GetValueOrDefault(key).GetValueOrDefault(key2);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So I tested that and I'm still running into the same issues.
Am I supposed to inject `Configuration` or `ErrorCode` in `ErrorCodeConfig` if I follow what you did? I tried with `ErrorMap` but it still won't populate `Type`

Comment: @user3656237: Can you do exactly the same as I did, just to establish some common ground? BR

Comment: Fair enough. So here is what I currently have in `ConfigureServices`:
https://codeshare.io/21r7bB
This throws `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'dictionary')'`

Edit: adding codeshare link

Comment: I'm running the debugger and it's very odd, `Configuration` is populated fine, but `ErrorMap` remains `null`

Comment: @user3656237: Both `Console.WriteLine(errorMap.Get("Input", "Name").Code);` and `Console.WriteLine(errorMap.Get("Input", "Name").Message);` working here.

Comment: Oh my bad! I had a typo that I did not catch. I'm sorry about that. It's working as well. I'm going to accept your answer, thank you so much for your time!

My guess now, is that I can run something like this to make this injectable:
 `services.AddSingleton(errorMap);`